# Prove that there are an infinity of prime $ak+b$, $a$ and $b$ coprimes

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

We have to integers $a,b$. I need to show that if $a$ and $b$ are coprimes then the set of prime numbers of kind $ak+b$ is infinite.

How could I show it ? I know how to do that for $4k+3$ or $4k+1$, but I have no idea how to get the general answer.

Comment: Hmmm...your question's title question is a rather involved theorem by Dirichlet, with a long and not so elementary proof.

Comment: This is a fairly difficult theorem, called [Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) Unless you are in a course in analytic number theory, I doubt it would be assigned as homework. And probably not even then!  The case $b=1$ is more "elementary" but still quite difficult.

Comment: @amWhy Yeah that's what i mean

Comment: The case $6k+5$ is easy. Already the method for $4k+1$ involves some number-theoretic machinery. But considerations about quadratic residues are enough, and also work for some other "small" cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, this is [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) and requires some fairly involved analytic number theory. There is probably not a simple proof.

You can find an [English translation of Dirichlet's original paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1408) online, but I haven't checked the translation for accuracy, relevance, or legibility (because it is beyond me!)

Comment: Ok thank you i'll look at it then

Comment: Wise decision, @Hippalectryon. Just FYI, you need quite a good ground in: group theory and general abstract algebra, complex analysis, analytic number theory, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, if i'm stuck on some point, i'll just look it up on google or ask on stackexchange :) - Besides, given the complexity of this, i guess my teacher just wanted me to think a bit about it without actually solving it (it is obviously beyond my abilities), so i think that just understanding the main points in the proof would be good enough for me.

Comment: These notes by A.J. Hildebrand contain a proof too: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/. (As you can see it covers an entire chapter of 20 pages, but the intuition behind it is explained quite well.)